# Can't get labels and buttons to move to the correct position on grid using row and column

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to programming and for a class assignment I need to create a tkinter Gui. I have to arrange 2 Labels, 3 Buttons, and 2 text boxes to specific positions. I input through grid what row or column I want, but they aren't moving.

I have tried doing one at a time, but then the only label doesn't move from the top left. I've tried doing it after all the different labels and buttons have been coded in, and they move slightly, or not to where I want them.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Form 1")
root.geometry("300x300")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

lbl1 = Label(app, text = "Label1")
lbl1.grid(row=4, column=2)

lbl2 = Label(app, text = "Label2")
lbl2.grid(row=2, column=2)

lbl3 = Label(app, text = "Label3")
lbl3.grid(row=8, column=6)

bttn1 = Button(app, text = "Button 1")
bttn1.grid(row=20, column=1)

bttn2 = Button(app, text = "Button 2")
bttn2.grid(row=20, column=6)

bttn3 = Button(app, text = "Button 3")
bttn3.grid(row=20, column=11)

txt1 = Entry().grid()
txt2 = Entry().grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The link at the end is not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Empty rows and empty columns have a size of zero unless you've used `rowconfigure` and/or `columnconfigure` to give them a minimum or uniform size. In such a case, row 1000 will appear immediately below row 0.

Comment: So are you saying i need a row column  in every slot first before moving things or are you saying i need to use row/column configure before continuing?

Comment: Here is a good reference for Bryan Oakley's suggestion:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-config.html

Comment: @WilliamKleinknechtBarasu13: I don't know what you need. If you want an empty row to have size, you have to tell tkinter what size to make it. You can either configure that row or column any time you want, or you need to put something in that row or column to give it a size. There's not enough information in your question to say anything more specific.